# Processing HTML form with c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am a newbie to C# development. I created an HTML form, and I want to run its input using C#.

My HTML form right now:

```
<form action="default.aspx.cs" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="first_name"  id="fname" 
     placeholder="e.g. Jane Doe" required  maxlength="20" >
    <p>
        Please specify a file, or a set of files:<br>
        <input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
    </p>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <!--<input type="submit" value="Submit"> -->
    </div>
</form>
```

My Default.aspx.cs file contains:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

I want to pass the contents from the html form to that Button1_Click function. The name input is there as a dummy field, my actual job is to get that file.

Comment: Why aren't you using the ASP .NET controls for your inputs?  There are *many* tutorials and examples demonstrating how to do that for beginners.  For non-control inputs, you can still get everything that was posted from the `Request` object.  Form data, files, etc.

Comment: lets say i change the name input to:                                               <asp:TextBox id="fname" required placeholder="jane doe"  runat="server" />       .  what else would i need to get the input from fname to my other file?

Comment: Then assuming nothing else is wrong, the value would be available in `fname.Text`

Answer (score 0):

You can access the values through the Request.Form object like so;

```
Request.Form["fname"]
```

Or you can do it the more correct way, by changing the `<input>` tags to be `<asp:TextBox>` tags, you can then access them by name eg. `fname.Text`